# Converting Byte to SByte

Tags: vb.net, casting, overflow

I'm reading bytes from a serial port, but I need to convert them to signed, 8-bit integers (SByte). Unfortunately, the overflow checking in Visual Basic prevents a Byte value of 255 from becoming -1 in an SByte. So, essentially, I want to do the following:

```
uint8_t a = 255;
int8_t b = (int8_t)a;    // b == -1
```

How can I do this in Visual Basic?

Comment: uint will be unsigned right? so if a=-1 b will be googley gunk

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz: the above C code will simply take the bytes, as they are stored in a and place them in b. Since a = 255 (0b11111111), then b will be also be 0b11111111 and will thus be interpreted as -1, assuming the compiler is using 2's complement notation to store signed integers.

Comment: no matter what you assume, as soon as you try applying arithmetic or printing b you're going to get something unexpected. That is, unless you are actually trying to contribute to the The International Obfuscated C Code Contest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can do this manually in Visual Basic using [IIf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as follows:

```
Dim a as Byte = 255
Dim b as SByte = IIf(a < 128, a, a - 256)
```

Answer (score 2):

VB doesn't seem like the best option for wrangling bits. Maybe you could have a separate assembly in C# for this, where you could just do :

```
byte b = 255;
sbyte sb = (sbyte) b;
```

(runtime operations are unchecked by default in C#)

Or, you *could* turn off overflow checking at the VB project level.

Project properties-> Compile-> Advanced Compiler Option-> [X] Remove integer overflow checks

And now, you just need to cast! No arithmetic!

```
Dim b As Byte = 255
Dim sb As SByte = CSByte(b)
```